# Ruby. Align Output to right AND left at the same time

Tags: ruby, formatting

I have this Hash

```
itemHash = {"124"=>["shoes", "59.99"],
            "456"=>["pants", "49.50"], 
            "352"=>["socks", "3.99"]}
```

I need to diplay it like this, with Description aligned to the left and Price to the right

```
Item    Description     Price
-----   --------------  -----
124     shoes           59.99
352     socks            3.99
456     pants           19.50
```

but when I try this code

```
itemHash.each do |a,b|
  print " #{a}     "
  b.each do |c,d|
    print ("%8s %5s" % [c,d])
  end
  puts
end
```

I get this

```
 Item    Description      Price
 ----    -----------      -----

 124        shoes         59.99
 456        pants         49.50
 352        socks          3.99
```

I've tried "print ("%8s %5-s" % [c,d])" and "print ("%-8s %5s" % [c,d])" but neither does it right. For some reason when I align the description (c) it automatically applies it to the price (d). Anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your `b.each do |c,d|` loop is actually yielding each item in the array and attempting to destructure what isn't there, so you get:

```
"%8s %5s" % ["shoes", nil]
"%8s %5s" % ["59.55", nil]
```

etc.

You just need to omit your inner loop:

```
itemHash.each do |a,b|
  print " #{a}     "
  print "%-8s %5s" % b
  puts
end
```

Or more simply:

```
itemHash.each {|a, b| puts format(" %-8s%-8s%5s", a, *b) }
```

Comment: Ay that worked, You're a saint. I was breaking my head on that for a solid 30 minutes.